# Criando um Entry formatado como moeda em Python (Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Gostaria de saber como seria a aplicação de uma formatação em um campo `Entry`, utilizando o `tkinter`, para o formato de valor com casas decimais e pontuação de milhar, no caso, `000.000.000,00`.Tentei adaptar um código parecido para CPF que inclusive esta aqui no stackoverflow mas sem sucesso.
Grato.

Segue código do CPF

```
    
    text = entry.get().replace(".", "").replace("-", "")[:11]
    new_text = ""

    if event.keysym.lower() == "backspace": return
    
    for index in range(len(text)):
        
        if not text[index] in "0123456789": continue
        if index in [2, 5]: new_text += text[index] + "."
        elif index == 8: new_text += text[index] + "-"
        else: new_text += text[index]

    entry.delete(0, "end")
    entry.insert(0, new_text)


from tkinter import *
screen = Tk()

entry = Entry(screen, font = ("Arial", 20))
entry.bind("<KeyRelease>", format_cpf)
entry.pack()
screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazer a adaptação colocando um contador e corrigindo a posição no index

```
for index in range(len(text)):
        cont=len(text)
        if not text[index] in "0123456789": continue
        if index in [cont-3]: new_text += text[index] + ","
        elif index in [cont-6,cont-9]: new_text += text[index] + "."
        else: new_text += text[index]
```

Segue código completo

```
def format_valor(event = None):
    
    text = entry.get().replace(",", "").replace(".", "")[:11]
    new_text = ""

    if event.keysym.lower() == "backspace": return

    
    
    for index in range(len(text)):
        cont=len(text)
        if not text[index] in "0123456789": continue
        if index in [cont-3]: new_text += text[index] + ","
        elif index in [cont-6,cont-9]: new_text += text[index] + "."
        else: new_text += text[index]
    
    entry.delete(0, "end")
    entry.insert(0, new_text)


from tkinter import *
screen = Tk()

entry = Entry(screen, font = ("Arial", 20))
entry.bind("<KeyRelease>", format_valor)
entry.pack()
screen.mainloop()
```